# Could the word 'wench' be used by a German mother to her young daughter in an affectionate teasing way when she had done something endearing?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm wanting to write a poem about a young girl in Leipzig in the 1700s. Her mother is teasing her as she has done something endearing. Would a mother have used the word 'wench' affectionately in such a circumstance? Thanks.

Comment: Germans speak German. I don’t understand your question.

Comment: welcome to German.SE. Not sure what your mother tongue is - questions can be in German as well. Do you have any (online) dictionary explaining the german word "wench"? I do not, I barely find https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=zeit&q=wench  = an english word. So in case this is an english word - why do you think a german mother would use it in the 1700s in Leipzig?  If you ask about the german translation of it - which one?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to assume German's don't speak German and shows no prior effort to find a translation.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

The reason why a German mother wouldn't have used this word is very simple: She speaks German, but *"wench"* is not a German word. It's an archaic English word and it means *"a lower class girl, a child servant, a promiscuous young woman, a prostitute".* There is no reason why a German speaking person should use a word that doesn't exist in the vocabulary of her language.

There are German words that derive from the same Indo-European root as *wench* which is *"*ueng-"*, but they have other meanings. The original meaning of the Indo-European verb was *"to bend; to sway; to make bent, swaying or curved movements".*

These are the modern German words derived from this root:

- winken (verb) = *to wave, to beckon*
- der Wink (noun) = *the hint, the sign*
- (ab)winkeln (verb) = *to bend, to curve, to angle*
- der Winkel (noun) = *the chevron, the corner, the nook*
- winkelig (adjective) = *angular, angled*
- wanken (verb) = *to stagger, to falter, to waver*
- wankend (participle; adjective) = *wavering, shaky*

Just for completeness:
The English verb *to wink* and the noun *the wink* also derive from the same root, but today they are false friends of the German words listed above. They translate into German as follows:

- to wink = *blinzeln, zwinkern*
- the wink = *das Blinzeln, das Zwinkern, das Augenzwinkern, der Augenblick*

Also *to wank* (to masturbate) derives from the same root, but it again has another meaning, that today no longer overlaps with the meanings of the other words.

---

Btw: German translations for the English noun *"wench"* are:

- die Maid = the female servant, the wench
- das Frauenzimmer = the dame, the broad, the wench
- die Hure = the prostitute, the whore, the harlot, the bitch, the wench
- die Landpomeranze = the hillbilly, the country pumpkin, the country wench

Maybe your German lady used one of these German words?

Comment: Not that I doubt any of this and only as a constructive critique, a few links would make the answer even better, for instance the "*ueng-" meaning bent. In case someone wants to dig deeper ...

Comment: @a_donda: Sorry, I don't have a link to the  "*ueng-" meaning. I took it from a printed book: *"DUDEN - Das Herkunftswörterbuch", 3. Auflage 2001, ISBN 3-411-04073-4, entry »winken« on page 930*

Comment: "Wench" is more historical than archaic; a modern English speaker would understand it and you might see it fiction set between the Renaissance and the 18th century. So if the poem was set in England instead of Leipzig then "wench" would not be out of place. When fiction is written in English, the characters speak in English, even if it's set in Ancient Greece. So unless the poem is in German, I don't see a problem with characters using 18th century English terms in a poem set in the 18th century, no matter where it's set.

Comment: Its clear from the context given in the question, that none of the suggestions below the ruler fits sufficiently to be seriously considered.

Comment: @RDBury: that's valuable info. I suggest 'das Luder' or 'das Luderchen', then, but unsure if it was used in the 17hundreds with this connotation (it meant patch, or fuse for blakpowder guns, I think) Much has changed ...

Comment: @a_donda: I'm pretty sure *Luder* wouldn't work as a translation. A "wench" could be any young woman, especially a pretty one, regardless of virtue. But it probably wouldn't refer to anyone in the upper class, or anyone unwilling to tolerate a certain amount of what would now be called sexual harassment. I'm thinking the character of Sally in [The Scarlet Pimpernel](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Scarlet_Pimpernel/3) is the archetypal "wench" when it comes to historical fiction. But how it was actually used in the 18th century is not my area of expertise.

Comment: PS. It's difficult to know how authentic to make the dialog with historical fiction. Some historical phrases aren't going to be understood by modern audiences and so should be avoided, but some modern phrases will be noticeable anachronisms and should also be avoided. I'm not sure that all these subtleties are within the scope of GLSE, even for works in German. Some word choices are more about the craft of writing than about the language itself.

Comment: A very old occurance is "Thou hast committed - Fornication: but that was in another country, and besides, the wench is dead."  Christopher Marlowe., 1589.